# Big O Notation confusion for bubble sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

I'm looking into the time complexities for various algorithms.

Taking the bubble sort algorithm specifically. It states that it has O(n2) worse-case time complexity. Wouldn't this mean that if we have 5 elements in an array to sort, this will take 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 times to sort it at a the worst case?

However, the algorithm is actually like this (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) ... etc.

Therefore with 5 elements in an array to sort, the time would be 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 , therefore 15 at worst case and not 25. Why is it still stated as O(n2) ? Thanks

Comment: The first thing you (should) learn about big O is that O(cf(n)) =O(f(n)) and O(f(n)+c) =O(f(n)) where c is any constant

Comment: Note that `(n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1 = n*(n-1)/2` and for large `n` the largest term is `n*n/2`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to unpack here! I'll start with some background information.

Firstly, big O notation is for asymptotic behavior. In this case that means that the algorithm will run no worse than a constant (positive) number multiplied by n^2. This means the algorithm is bounded above by some positive constant multiplied by n^2. Note that this constant could be a fraction.
In many cases it is difficult to determine asymptotic behavior by only examining cases when n is small-- after all, we are interested in how BubbleSort behaves when n is very large. Otherwise, sorting the small list would be trivial.

You highlighted that the algorithm behaves in such a way that (n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1 operations are performed in the worst case. The sum of the first n positive integers is equal to (n*(n+1))/2. We see here that the result has an n^2 term, though it is divided by 2. The wonderful thing about asymptotic notation is that we do not need to concern ourselves with constant coefficients nor do we concern ourselves with smaller terms added or subtracted from the leading/largest term. What matters is how the number of operations grows with n as n becomes increasingly large.

With this algorithm, the number of operations grows in quadratic time (that is, grows with n^2) in the worst case. This algorithm is bounded above by C*n^2, where C is some positive real number constant. That is why is it stated that the running time of this algorithm is O(n^2), even though the number of operations may not be exactly n^2.

Answer (score 1):

Because those are the rules. When dealing with Big-O notation, you take only the largest magnitude term.

Bubble sort is slightly less than n^2 operations worse case, but for sufficiently high values of n, the difference between that and n^2 is very low, so we just hand wave it away and say it's O(n^2)